# App crash on System.load()

Tags: android, android-ndk

I try to load a NDK library with

```
    File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "mylib.so");
    System.load(file.getAbsolutePath());`
```

And it normally works, but some of my customers report app crashes on Samsung Galaxy S3 (may be since the last update to 4.1.1). Now I have a Galaxy S3 here and in fact it crashes :( The app crashes completely during the System.load() call and I receive no exceptions, only one error message in LogCat:

```
12-11 10:50:03.510: A/libc(29583): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x5d53901c (code=2), thread 29583 (trol.myapp)
```

Does anyone have an idea what can be wrong?

Comment: can't it be some problem with your .so? what does the full error trace says?

Comment: Yes, it may be a problem with the library. But LogCat contains only one error message. Where else I can search for "full error trace"? Do you have an idea?

Comment: Maybe kernel log if you can access it...

Answer (score 0):

use `System.loadLibrary` instead of `System.load`

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but it didn't help. I still have the same problem. I think the library is broken.

Answer (score 0):

@Valelik: Get exactly the same problem: A NDK lib that did work fine so far, and started to crash in the same way (a SIGSEGV due to the System.load() call) on Jelly Bean. Went around googling, and I did not find anything.. In my case the system continuously tries to load the lib and crashes, and so on..
Any update in this issue?

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that the File Object is being garbage collected before the library can look into it's memory of the path. Try saving the File as class variable.

Comment: I don't think so. At least I can debug and the variable file is here and the getAbsolutePath() returns a valid value.